# Phase Portrait of this Non-linear System

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot phase portrait of a Hamiltonian of Duffing equation using Python.

The Hamiltonian is
                                   *H(u,v)= (3b/32)(u²+v²)² - (s/2)(u²+v²) - K·u*

Here I set
                          *b = 8/3*, *K = 1*, *s = 2*, ⇒ *H(u,v)= (u²+v²)²/4 - (u²+v²) - u*

I know how to implement it in WolframALpha,

[image]

```
StreamPlot[{y, (1/4) (x^2 + y^2)^2 -(x^2 + y^2) - x},{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4}]
```

Can someone help me to implement this in Python using Matplotlib?

[additional question]

Is there a way to plot the stream of this equation in 3d?

Comment: Have you actually tried searching for matplotlib streamplot yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point to keep in mind is that you have to create 2D arrays of the velocities of the vectorfield `U, V` by using the meshgrid `np.mgrid`. Use the code below as a starting point and don't forget to play around with the [options of streamplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html).

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  
# define the grid on which to plot the vectorfield
# here: a grid of 100 x 100 points between -4 and 4
a = 4
Y, X = np.mgrid[-a:a:100j, -a:a:100j] 

U = Y
V = 1/4.*(X**2 + Y**2)**2 - (X**2 + Y**2) - X
  
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4, 4)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density = 1)
ax.set_xlabel(u'x') 
ax.set_ylabel(u'y')
  
plt.show()
```

yields:  [image: streamplot in matplotlib]